# Titanium ellipsize property is not working for Label in iOS

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-sdk

In iOS ellipsize property is not working for me. The same code is working for android. I have attached the iOS screenshot for iOS issue below. Please help me to understand If I am missing something.

Thanks in Advance!!!

**Ti SDK: v9.0.3GA**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Demo App',
    backgroundColor: '#DCDCDC',
    layout: 'vertical'
});

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
});


var firstLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Hello, This is for testing. I wanted to check Ti Ellipsize property ...',
    height: 'auto',
    right: '10',
    top: '50',
    left: '10',
    color: '#F0F0F0',
    font: { fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Arial' },
    //horizontalWrap: true,
    wordWrap: false,
    ellipsize: true,
    maxlines: 1
});

row.add(firstLabel);

tableView.setData([row]);

win.add(tableView);
win.open();
```

[image: Android and iOS simulator Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did research on this above issue and I came to know in iOS its automatically applied **ellipsize** property to your labels. The only thing we need to take care is height property if possible remove or assigned **Ti.UI.SIZE**.

I have modified my above code and mentioned here in this post. I write a conditional logic for android device.

```
var deviceDetect = require('./deviceDetect');
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Demo App',
    backgroundColor: '#DCDCDC',
    layout: 'vertical'
});

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
});


var firstLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Hello, This is for testing. I wanted to check Ti Ellipsize property ...',
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    right: '10',
    top: '50',
    left: '10',
    color: '#F0F0F0',
    font: { fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Arial' },
    //wordWrap: false, //remove this deprecated in Ti v8.x
    ellipsize: deviceDetect.isAndroid() ? true : false,
    lines: deviceDetect.isAndroid() ? 1 : undefined
});

row.add(firstLabel);

tableView.setData([row]);

win.add(tableView);
win.open();
```